# How to create a custom contact group like Facebook did?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, addressbook

There are three main features:

- Custom group (Not a subgroup of iCloud like "Test" in my picture)
- Contacts have to be read only in this group
- Small Icon under each picture (see second picture; red arrow)

Is it possible to implement this 3 features programatically? 
[image: photo1]

[image: photo2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) See [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/Tasks/ManagingGroups.html) which explains how to add Person or Group record to Address Book.

2) AFAIK there is no way how to prevent the user from deleting the group or contacts in it.

3) Not possible. Facebook is integrated deep into iOS by Apple.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer.
It seems impossible to implement the icon feature.
But what about the other features?